# Continued: Installing on Mac Sierra: qt_gui_cpp_sip errors

Tags: osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's turning out to be really important for me to try and get ROS installed on Mac even though I realize its not a supported platform (yet). I've made it through lots of hurdles and learned more about python and packages and macOS and ROS than I ever thought possible!

This command fails:

```
bash-3.2$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

And at the end of the log it gives me this command to reproduce the problem. Here's the output:

```
cd /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp && /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8
[ 83%] Built target qt_gui_cpp
[ 88%] Running SIP generator for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
sip: Deprecation warning: qt_gui_cpp.sip:1: %Module version number should be specified using the 'version' argument
sip: Unable to find file "QtCore/QtCoremod.sip"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 78, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.19.3_1/bin/sip', '-c', '/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip', '-b', '/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/pyqtscripting.sbf', '-I', '/usr/local/share/sip/PyQt5', '-w', '-x', 'VendorID', '-t', 'WS_MACX', '-t', 'Qt_5_9_1', '-x', 'Py_v3', 'qt_gui_cpp.sip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
make[2]: *** [sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
bash-3.2$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266864/continued:-installing-on-mac-sierra:-qt_gui_cpp_sip-errors/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue is described in the installation docs in section 4.3: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source
You should manually create this link:

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/sip/Qt5 /usr/local/share/sip/PyQt5
```

Also check out my gist of successful ROS installation on macOS Sierra for solutions to further problems. I hope it helps somewhat.
https://gist.github.com/lubiluk/361a018b267ca4e3ce10cdc68b17363d

---

Originally posted by [lubiluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29460/lubiluk/) with karma: 48 on 2017-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2